# How i can create over screen div with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Help Me ...i want create a div tag that have a form with post method and i gonna when click a link or button, show this div and form with jquery like alert or photogallery . Help me please.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried to do so far ?

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<div id='popupDiv' style='display:none;'>
//your form here
</div>
<a href="#" id="show">Show div</a>
```

Then write script like,

```
<script>
$('#show').click(function(){
   $('#popupDiv').show();
});
</script>
```

You must include [jquery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js) in your page

Comment: work.tanks . did you see alert ? the background is transparent and block and show a box in center of screen . i want my form show in center of screen and have close button to return to HTML page if my user do not want submit the form

Answer (score -1):

Add opacity of previous background to lower than half and of div to the greater than half.

Comment: can you write a sample code ... my English is not good . :(  . i want show my form in center of screen and i have a opacity background like this site : http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-illustration-12976834-contact-us-icons-black-series.php

Comment: Click on the download button and see what happens